# How to solve ValueError: could not convert string to float in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have text file of dataset which look like this.

```
2.8858451e-001 -2.0294171e-002 -1.3290514e-001 -9.9527860e-001 -9.8311061e-001
```

When I had read this file and fit classifier on this data I get this error.

> ValueError: could not convert string to float: '  2.3177399e-001  4.9371571e-003

I'm using the following code:

```
tra_x, tra_y, tes_x, tes_y = np.array([]), np.array([]), np.array([]),np.array([]) 

file = open('train\X_train.txt', encoding='utf-8') 
tra_x = file.readlines()
tra_x = [float(x).split(" ") for x in tra_x] 

file = open('train\y_train.txt', encoding='utf-8') 
tra_y = file.readlines() 

file = open('test\X_test.txt', encoding='utf-8') 
tes_x = file.readlines() 

file = open('test\y_test.txt', encoding='utf-8') 
tes_y = file.readlines()
```

Comment: It would help if you show the code you use to read the file.

Comment: tra_x, tra_y, tes_x, tes_y = np.array([]), np.array([]), np.array([]),np.array([])
    file = open('train\X_train.txt', encoding='utf-8')
    tra_x = file.readlines()
    tra_x = [float(x).split(" ") for x in tra_x]
    file = open('train\y_train.txt', encoding='utf-8')
    tra_y = file.readlines()
    file = open('test\X_test.txt', encoding='utf-8')
    tes_x = file.readlines()
    file = open('test\y_test.txt', encoding='utf-8')
    tes_y = file.readlines()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code is working for a single line:

```
[float(x) for x in "2.8858451e-001 -2.0294171e-002 -1.3290514e-001 -9.9527860e-001 -9.8311061e-001".split(" ")]
```

The numbers are in a long string. You need to separate on the spaces and convert each string separately to float

for multiple lines:

```
return_list = []
for l in tra_x:
    for entry in l.split(" "):
        return_list.append(float(entry))
```

Comment: I had try this but get same error.
tra_x = [float(x).split(" ") for x in tra_x]

Comment: try tra_x = [float(x) for x in tra_x.split(" ")]

Comment: I get this error
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'split'

Comment: readlines is returning a list of the lines in file. So need to go through each line with another for loop

Comment: for i in tra_x:
        train_x = [float(x) for x in i.split(" ")]

Comment: please add an example for the data in your question